# jQuery slideUp after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation menu child ul animating when it's parent li is hovered with the mouse. It also slides up when the mouse exits. However, I am trying to get it to delay by 1 second before it slides up. I want the child ul to remain open for 1 second after the mouse leaves. However, it is still sliding up immediately. What's wrong here?

```
    $(".ipro_menu li>ul").hide(); // Hide all

$(".ipro_menu li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).children("ul").slideUp(); // Wait 1 sec before sliding up
});
```

Comment: a jsFiddle would be nice. I think that @adeneo is correct, but I wonder about side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong order, get the elements before you delay the animation, otherwise the delay is applied to `this`, not it's children.

```
$(this).children("ul").delay(1000).slideUp();
```